# Emacs org-mode TAB not working to unfold headings

Tags: emacs, org-mode, key-bindings

Ok I have to say I’m a bit stuck here. I am used to have conflicts between my mac os (at home) and my windows (at work) configuration which use the same .emacs.d init file.
I have recently changed my professionnal computer and needed to synchronize my init file again and now the TAB key which usually fold and unfold heading in org (one of the moste usefull and used key in org I would say) doesn’t work. But it works on my mac OS with the exact same configuration.
Another strange behaviour is that when I use Shift-TAB it actually unfold everything (but only on se second click...)
Is someone out there that have any explanation to this? I’m a bit lost.

I can print my init file here if needed.

Comment: What does `C-h` `k` `Tab` show?

Comment: TAB (translated from <tab>) runs the command evil-jump-forward (found
in evil-motion-state-map), which is an interactive byte-compiled Lisp
function in ‘evil-commands.el’.

It is bound to TAB.

(evil-jump-forward &optional COUNT)

Go to newer position in jump list.
To go the other way, press C-o.

Comment: So, that's it. For me, it runs `org-cycle` - because I don't use evil commands.

Comment: Seems you are in evil-mode. Either press i to switch to insert state (<N> in the status changes to <I>), then TAB should work. Or press <C-z> to switch to Emacs state (<E> in the status). If you don't need evil, disable it in the config.

Comment: I actually really need evil. The thing is TAB’s behaviour should be the same in all state: insert, emacs, motion even visual I guess.

Comment: If you need evil, you could try package `evil-org` (https://github.com/Somelauw/evil-org-mode).